# clear the outputPath before the next release for Azure DevOps of Angular 6 + asp.net application

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I am using Azure Devops to deploy Angular 6 + asp.net application.

ng build --prod command perfectly deploying to destination folder which is in  outputPath of angular.json

During release definition(CD),  we need to clear all the files in the existing outputPath.

Because existing web deployment already having  main.{oldhashvalue}.js.

if I am doing next release definition then it adds another main.{newhashvalue}.js to the same outputPath.

This creates the issue that the application still refers the old main.{oldhashvalue}.js.

So, how to clean  old outputPath before the next deploy during release definition?

Here is the YAML format of release definition

steps:

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3

  displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service to Slot'

  inputs:

  azureSubscription: 'azureSubscription - Service Endpoint'

  WebAppName: firstwebappname

  DeployToSlotFlag: true

  ResourceGroupName: firstresourcegroupname

  SlotName: dev

  Package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)***.zip'

  TakeAppOfflineFlag: true

  UseWebDeploy: true

  RenameFilesFlag: true

I already tried enabling "Remove additional files at destination" option but it clears the node_modules folder which is needed always. Don't wanted to install all the time.

[image]

Comment: Is there a _Publish Using Web Deploy_ options above the _Remove add'l files_?

Comment: Yes. it is checked.

Comment: My bad, that's showing in the yaml as well.  What about a task to delete files in the outputpath before build?

Comment: Build process cleans the previous outputPath. I verified the deployment zip file. This issue is happening during the release definition. Before it deploy, it has to clear the outputPath folder.

Comment: Can you add a delete files task to the Release pipeline then?

Comment: Delete files task deletes from source path. Not from the destination path where we deploy the application. I am not sure what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

During build, direct your output to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. That folder is cleared out every time a build runs.

Comment: it is pointing to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory). Build works fine as expected. I verified that after build is success , downloaded the Build artifacts zip and verified the location. It clears the files.

Comment: @ggn979 Then I don't understand what you're asking. Either you're having a problem related to your build process, or you're having a problem related to your deployment process. Update your question to explain at which exact point you're encountering a problem.

Comment: Daniel Mann, in my previous comment I missed the information on Release definition. Here it is.....Build Definition is works fine.  This issue is happening during the release definition. Before it deploy, it has to clear the outputPath folder. I don't want to enable  "Remove additional files at destination". Because it will remove node_modules . I mentioned this in my question.

Comment: I don't understand what "outputPath folder" means in this context. The release has no outputPath. Are you talking about **the file system of the Azure Web App**?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I am using Angular + asp.net application. Angular has settings(angular.json) called outputPath where it deploys all compiled js files of the Angular Application.